# Model View ViewModel in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mvvm

I am presently reading [Manning's AngularJS in Action by Lukas Ruebbelke](http://www.manning.com/ruebbelke/CH1_sample.pdf)
In Chapter One, he puts forward,

> The controller is responsible for providing state for the view to bind
>   to and commands
>       that the view can issue back to the controller to do units of work. This frees up
>       the view from having to maintain state (since it only has to display whatever state the
>       controller is in) and it frees up the view from having to do any work (as the view always
>       defers to the controller).

[image]

What does he mean by  ***providing state for the view to bind to***?

Furthermore, down the line, he suggests,

> Using a ViewModel inverts the application flow that traditionally
>   existed in jQuerystyle
>       applications. In jQuery, you would’ve queried the DOM and attached an event listener.
>       When that event fired, you would try to interpret the event and parse the DOM
>       for state so that you could perform some imperative operation. This forces a tight coupling
>       between the HTML and the JavaScript that drives it. By introducing a ViewModel,
>       you’re able to break this relationship. The controller no longer is responsible
>       for listening to the view, but rather the view is responsible for issuing specific commands
>       to the controller that it operates on.

The last line confuses me.

The ***controller*** no longer is responsible for listening to the ***view***, 
but rather the ***view*** is responsible for ***issuing specific commands*** to the ***controller*** that it operates on.

Isn't saying like the son is no longer responsible to listen to his father, but rather the father is responsible for ***issuing specific commands*** to the ***son*** that it(son) has to operate on.

Even if the son is not responsible, the son is actually made responsible. But aren't they(both) above statements are alike.

What exactly is he trying to say?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I understand it.

In angular, the **view** is your HTML, the **controllers** are your angular controllers (no surprise on this one) and the **ViewModel** is the `$scope` object which you can access from **either** the controller or the view (it's kind of like the glue that links the controller to the view).

**Providing state for the view to bind** means that the view only knows how to display the data (i.e. it knows how the data is structured) but in any case, it does not hold the **actual data**. This data/state is held by the controller who **binds** it to the view by "putting" the data on the `$scope` object thus letting the view access the data and display it.

> The controller no longer is responsible for listening to the view, but
>   rather the view is responsible for issuing specific commands to the
>   controller that it operates on.

This is a **tell don't ask** design pattern. Instead of having the controller ask the the view if anything has changed, the view will tell the controller if such a thing happened.

e.g.: Imagine we have a form with a submit button. Instead of having the controller ask the view if someone clicked the submit button like in jQuery:

```
$('submitButton').on('click', doSomething);
```

The view will issue a specific command (method) that the controller will execute. The view is thus telling the controller that someone submitted the form:

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
      //process form here
    }
  }]);
```

View:

```
<button ng-click="submit()">Submit Form</button>
```

As you can see, we "attach" the `submit()` method onto the `$scope` object so that we can call `submit` from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these examples. Here is the jQuerystyle app:

```js
jQuery('element').on('click', clickHandler);
```

The controller grabs an element from the view and binds to it.

Here is an Angular example where the relationship is inverted. Now the Controller exposes a handler and the view is binding to it.

```js
function Controller() {
    this.clickHandler = function(){};
}
```

```html
<button type="button" click="vm.clickHandler()">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: click="vm.clickHandler()" should be ng-click="vm.clickHandler()"

Answer (score 0):

**Scope** is an integral part of Angular, which is really another term for **ViewModel**. **$scope** is the "glue" (ViewModel) between a controller and a view.

The way it works in Angular is you have a View, which is what we’ve been doing     with our Directives, our Filters and our Data Binding.
But we don’t want to put all of our logic into the View because it’s not very maintainable or testable or all those types of things.

Instead we’re going to have a special little JavaScript object – a container - called a Controller. The Controller will drive things. It’s going to control ultimately what data gets bound into the View. If the View passes up data to the controller it will handle passing off maybe to a service which then updates a back-end data store.

The glue between the View and the Controller is something called the Scope, and in Angular you’re going to see a lot of objects or variables that start with $. $scope represents the scope object.

When I say it’s the glue, it literally is the thing that ties the controller to the view.

[See this image to understand $scope (View Model).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yLsG.png)

**The view doesn’t have to know about the controller, and the controller definitely doesn’t want to know about the view.**

You’ll see that the view can know about the controller because there’s a directive for that if you’d like to use it but the controller itself, to make it testable and a few things – loosely coupled and modular and all that good stuff – shouldn’t know anything about the view. In fact you should be able to define a controller that you can bind to different views. Maybe you have a mobile view, you have a desktop view or whatever it may be.
So the scope is this glue between them.